# How to debug a flutter redux application

Tags: flutter, flutter-redux

I am new to flutter and will be implementing the redux framework in my flutter app. I would like to monitor the state of my application and thus, would like to know if I could use a redux flutter debugger.

Comment: It's here on official site, but you need to go through it... https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/debugging#dart-observatory-statement-level-single-stepping-debugger-and-profiler

Since your question is not regarding portion of a code, we don't know where you stuck, and what to fix. so, it's hard to tell you.. here's another link https://medium.com/flutter-community/developing-and-debugging-flutter-apps-for-ios-without-a-mac-8d362a8ec667 .

Comment: I want to be able to view the state changes that take place in the redux store of the flutter app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Flutter Redux Time Travel](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_redux_dev_tools) built by Brian Egan, the same person who made the `flutter_redux` package. With this you can debug redux states in your app and also see the previous states that you have gone through.

The implementation is pretty easy. While developing you use a `DevToolsStore` instead of a normal `Store` and use it in your `StoreProvider`.

```
// Create a DevToolsStore instead of a normal Store during Development
final devStore = DevToolsStore<MyAppState>(
  myReducer,
  initialState: MyAppState()
);
```

Your `StoreProvider` should look like this:

```
StoreProvider(
     store: this.devStore,
     child: MaterialApp(
     // Omitting some boilerplate here
     home: Scaffold(
       endDrawer: ReduxDevTools<MyAppState>(store),
     ),
   ),
);
```

What you will see is a **Drawer Hamburger Icon** on the right side of your app bar which will help you to navigate through the app states.